# Loading a rtf file in a windows store app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, rtf

I am trying to load a rtf file in a windows store app, however this file comes with a style and sometimes that style is applied and ohter times isn't. This behaviour is **TOTALLY** random (If I rerun the app over and over again sometimes the container I am using uses the style, other doesn't).

I am using a `RichEditBox` only because [RichTextBlock doesn't support rtf files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/72e7cd23-715f-4985-ac1d-3e69ac5c25d3).

I have a `RichEditBox` in the MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <RichEditBox 
        x:Name="InfoContentView"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Background="{x:Null}"
        Foreground="#FFFFFF"/>
</Grid>
```

And then I inject the rtf file like this:

```
 this.InfoContentView.IsReadOnly = false;
 this.InfoContentView.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, 
                                       textContent);
 this.InfoContentView.IsReadOnly = true;
```

`Textcontent` is loaded from application package. I supose that works since I see the text perfectly, even links work fine.

I have tried to put the Document text before each execution to empty. Also, I have added a button to refresh the behaviour and it doesnt work in the first execution but then, after I press the button several times, it is consistent.

I only wish that the behaviour is consistent. I don't care if I have to format the file in the file or in the application.

The rtf file is quite simple and you can download the rtf file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11200725/test.rtf).

Comment: This is undiagnosable when you don't post minimum repro RTF.  Quacks like a bug, contact Microsoft Support for assistance.

Comment: I suppose that you are saying that you need the rtf file I am using? If so here it is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11200725/test.rtf . It is a file quite simple, so I didnt upload it. I have made some changes and I will provide more info in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is ackward. I don't know if this is a bug or if I shouldn't be doing this.

This grid was inside another grid that had `Visibility = Collapsed`. It turns out that if I had the Visiblity equals to collapsed and then I change it to visible it would have this random behaviour. I have hidden it using the opacity and then it works. Although with this solution I had to do some hacky stuff so I could get touches in that area when the opacity is set to 0.

I am not satisfied with my answer, but it might save someone else time. I will accept any answer that explains this behaviour.